# UnityFramework.framework contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'. Getting this error while getting Unity IOS build

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

On my Unity project, I took several builds before without a problem. However, in this build, I integrated Facebook SDK and then this error (image1) started appearing when I try to upload it after archiving it on the Xcode workspace.[image]

I also tried to upload it with Transporter, but Transporter also threw errors (image2).[image]

When I build the project for IOS unity creates some files and there I found a UnityFramework folder, I think this folder is the mentioned folder in the error. However, there are only 2 files in this folder and none is named "Frameworks"(image3).[image]

Here are the build options of the project at Xcode workspace (image4):[image]

With the Android build of the app, everything is okay. This issue appears only with the  IOS build.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's a visual representation of what you should do to resolve the `"contains disallowed file 'Frameworks'" errors` in XCode projects exported from Unity

[image]

1. Click on Unity-iPhone project
2. Click on the UnityFramework Target
3. Click on the Build Settings
4. Search for "swift"
5. Set the "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries" option to "No"

- **IMPORTANT** Remember to change the build settings of the "UnityFramework" target NOT the "Unity-iPhone" target

Or

If you don't want to configure this manually every time you build you can add this script in your project to do it automatically for you on each build:

```csharp
using System;
using UnityEditor;
#if UNITY_IOS
using UnityEditor.iOS.Xcode;
#endif
using UnityEditor.Callbacks;

namespace SomeEditorNameSpace
{
    // Automatically set the "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries" option to "No" in UnityFramework Target in XCode
    public static class DisableEmbedSwiftLibs
    {
        [PostProcessBuildAttribute(Int32.MaxValue)] //We want this code to run last!
        public static void OnPostProcessBuild(BuildTarget buildTarget, string pathToBuildProject)
        {
            #if UNITY_IOS
            if (buildTarget != BuildTarget.iOS) return; // Make sure its iOS build
            
            // Getting access to the xcode project file
            string projectPath = pathToBuildProject + "/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj";
            PBXProject pbxProject = new PBXProject();
            pbxProject.ReadFromFile(projectPath);
            
            // Getting the UnityFramework Target and changing build settings
            string target = pbxProject.GetUnityFrameworkTargetGuid();
            pbxProject.SetBuildProperty(target, "ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES", "NO");

            // After we're done editing the build settings we save it 
            pbxProject.WriteToFile(projectPath);
            #endif
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can Archive & Validate your build without any errors. Hope my answer helped.

Comment: Awesome answer! Thank you for the graphic. I wish stack overflow allowed tipping.

Answer (score 5):

Try to set the *Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries*. to *No*

Answer (score 4):

Yes, but Set the Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries in UnityFrameWork Build Settings, not in main app's Build Settings. That worked for me.

Comment: Set it to yes or no ?

Answer (score 3):

Changing the "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries" value to "No" in the UnityFramework's build settings solved this issue for me.

*Targets > UnityFramework > Build Settings > Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries > No*